# show data of highcharts from database table laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, highcharts, controller, laravel-blade

i want to display  my table information in highcharts.

this is my table schema:

[image]

i want to display the EventDateTime as **name** in highcharts

and X,Y,Z Values as **data** of highcharts

this is my code:

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('row', {

    chart: {
              type: 'column'
           },

           title: {
                text: 'EventDateTime'
           },

           legend: {
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                layout: 'vertical'
            },

            xAxis: {
                categories: ['X', 'Y', 'Z'],
                labels: {
                    x: -10
                }
            },

            yAxis: {
                allowDecimals: false,
                title: {
                    text: 'Values'
                }
            },

            series: [
               @foreach ($chart as $object)
               {
                  name: {!! json_encode($object->EventDateTime) !!},
                  data: [{!! json_encode($object->XValue) !!}, 
                         {!! json_encode($object->YValue) !!}, 
                         {!! json_encode($object->ZValue) !!}
                        ]
               },
               @endforeach
            ],

            responsive: {
                rules: [{
                    condition: {
                        maxWidth: 500
                    },
                    chartOptions: {
                        legend: {
                            align: 'center',
                            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                            layout: 'horizontal'
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            labels: {
                                align: 'left',
                                x: 0,
                                y: -5
                            },
                            title: {
                                text: null
                            }
                        },
                        subtitle: {
                            text: null
                        },
                        credits: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        });
```

controller code:

```
$chart = DB::table('tbl_graph')->select('*')->get();
        return view('admin.Charts.index',compact('chart'));
```

name is getting displayed.

my problem is i am not getting the data populated in chart.

what is the best way to do this...?

Comment: show ur code in controller

Answer (score 0):

change your highChart script as following:

in place of x-axis caregory :

```
xAxis: {
    //array of date print here
    categories: ['date1', 'date2', 'date3'],
    labels: {x: -10}
},
```

in place of series :

```
series: [

           {
              name: {X},
              data: [all x values here comma sepearted]
           },
           {
              name: {Y},
              data: [all y values here comma sepearted]
           },
           {
              name: {Z},
              data: [all z values here comma sepearted]
           },
        ],
```

You can take reference from this fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/xwea5a5b/